# Symfony Form Dynamic choices for Sonata Admin

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm in some kind of trouble with a Symfony/Sonata Form.

I have a Form-Text which has a category coming from an entity Category.
The category can have a parent category.

Let's say I have a category **Water** which has no parent. My text is about salted water, so I want to select the subCategory **Salted Water**.

How can I do that? I want to select **Water** in my select list of categories, so I can filter my children categories on a second select list with only **Water** related subCategories.

What would be the best approach to do so? I've seen a few jquery methods, but I'm trying to avoid Javascript on this solution, especially if there is a way to configure it.

Looking forward to your answers, I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: If you want something dynamic to happen without reloading the whole page, you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: Of course, but I meant that I don't want to overload my page with scripts (symfony and sonata already take some time to load so..)

Comment: It's impossible without JS

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Either use javascript or you have to reload the page and use this technique http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html